# Wordpress thumbnail with minimal dimensions

Tags: wordpress, thumbnails

Is there a way how to generate a thumbnail with specified minimal dimensions? For example, calling `the_post_thumbnail(array(100,100))` will return a thumbnail that would fit inside these dimensions (so its longest side has max 100px). I want kind a opposite to this – a thumbnail that its shorter side has at least 100px. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You add new size using [`add_image_size( $name, $width, $height, $crop );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size)
in your `function.php`.
Then you can use a plugin like [regenerate thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to regenerate your old images. It is safe to use but you have to test it on your own.
You can also create dynamically new sizes on using hook [`add_attachment`](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/add_attachment).